# Stripe Connect Express Test Account Not Updating Company Address

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments

I'm creating Stripe Connect Express accounts where users can create their own online store and process payments from customers.

This is what the code looks like to create the test account

```
        var options = new AccountCreateOptions
        {
            Type = "express",
            Country = "CA",
            Email = createAccount.Email,
            Capabilities = new AccountCapabilitiesOptions()
            {
                CardPayments = new AccountCapabilitiesCardPaymentsOptions
                {
                    Requested = true,
                },
                Transfers = new AccountCapabilitiesTransfersOptions
                {
                    Requested = true
                },
            }
        };
```

I then use the account Id generated from AccountCreateOptions to generate an Account Link where users will be redirected to a Stripe form to enter their business details (business address included).

What I need is to get the business address back from Stripe. But for some reason, the address does not show in the Connect Dashboard.

Even when I update the address manually it does not save.
There is a warning on the test user's profile that states:

```
Add missing information for person(s) listed on the account
More information is needed for some people listed on this account
How to resolve
Please instruct this account to contact Stripe support.
```

However, the Account API indicates the need for the user to provide their TaxID and verification documents, yet I can't find a place to input this information. I'm uncertain if this impacts the saving of the Business Address. It seems there might be a crucial step I'm overlooking. Any guidance on this would be immensely helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#redirect-link) for an Express account mentions

> Before creating the first account link for an Express account, (you can) prefill any Know Your Customer (KYC) information. After you create an account link for an Express account, you can’t read or update its KYC information.

An Express account has access to a Stripe Dashboard and is expected to provide any follow up / additional info that is necessary via their Dashboard after completing their onboarding via an Account Link. You can access the test express account's Dashboard by creating a [Login Link](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/login_link/create).

If you can't view or access the business address, that's probably because Stripe considers it as KYC info.

Comment: hi @alex, could you be more specific, please? In order to do the KYC for my customer, is it required for me to prefill their information in the onboarding url?

Comment: like what the Stripe docs mention, `you can` prefill, which indicates that it's optional. You can always try it out in test mode by not pre-filling information and see how it works. If you're doing this in test mode, you can use the test info listed in https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing